# Verifying whether a quotient ring is indeed a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Take $$\frac{\Bbb{R[x]}}{\langle x^2+1\rangle}$$ This is a ring. In this quotient ring, the product of equivalence classes $[a+bx]$ and $[c+dx]$ is another equivalence class, as a ring is closed under multiplication.

$[a+bx]=\{a+bx,a+bx+(x^2+1),a+bx+2(x^2+1),\dots\}$, and $[c+dx]=\{c+dx,c+dx+(x^2+1),c+dx+2(x^2+1),\dots\}$.

Also, we should have $[a+bx][c+dx]=[(ac+bdx^2)+(ad+bc)x]$.

Which two elements in $[a+bx]$ and $[c+dx]$ multiply with each other to give $(ac+bdx^2)+(ad+bc)x+(x^2+1)$, which is a member of $[(ac+bdx^2)+(ad+bc)x]$?

Note: I know that $\{a+bx,a+bx+(x^2+1),a+bx+2(x^2+1),\dots\}\neq[a+bx]$; it is only the inverse of $[a+bx]$. I only write all this for a clear exposition: $[m][n]=[mn]$ only because the inverse images of $[m]$ and $[n]$, under the canonical mapping, multiply together to give the inverse image of $[mn]$.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that $x^2 \equiv -1$ in the quotient; so $[ac+bdx^2 + (ad+bc)x] = [(ac-bd) + (ad+bc)x]$

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? If the question in the title (always the first guess), then proving that $\Bbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is a ring is a consequence of the fact that $R/I$ is a ring for all rings $R$ and ideals $I$. Verifying the axioms is easy (trivial even) after you realize that they are a consequence of the facts that $\Bbb{R}[x]$ is a ring, and that the operations are well defined. The latter (=the key) allows you to use whichever element of a coset you want in the definition of the operations. And what Prahlad said.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen- I'm looking for the elements in the preimages pf $[a+bx]$ and $[c+dx]$ which multiply together to give $(ac+bdx^2)+(ad+bc)x+(x^2+1)$

Comment: Why? You don't always get all the elements in a coset as products of elements of the factor cosets. Consider the hopefully easier and more familiar quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}=\Bbb{Z}_5$. I hope that you have no trouble understanding that in this ring you have $\overline{2}\cdot\overline{3}=\overline{6}=\overline{1}$. Yet here
$$\overline{2}=\{2,7,12,17,\ldots,-3,-8,\ldots\}$$ and
$$\overline{3}=\{3,8,13,18,\ldots,-2,-7,\ldots\},$$ so you cannot find numbers $a\in[2]=\overline{2}$ and $b\in[3]=\overline{3}$ such that $ab=1$. It's the same thing here.

Comment: (cont'd) The key is that the product of any members of the two cosets belong to the same coset. In the numerical example we initially worry about whether the product
$$2\cdot3, 12\cdot(-2), 17\cdot3, (-3)\cdot8$$ et cetera are all congruent modulo five (they are). We do not need to get all the elements in
$$\overline{1}=[1]=\{1,6,11,16,\cdots,-4,-9,\cdot\}$$ as products.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen- That clears up a mountain of things!. On what basis are the following true then: $[m]+[n]=[m+n]$ and $[m][n]=[mn]$? Are they completely arbitrary, defined thus because the axioms of a ring are complied with? I was under the impression that $[m]+[n]=[m+n]$ because the preimages of $[m]$ and $[n]$ add up to give the pre-image of $[m+n]$: and the same for $[m][n]$.

Comment: Yeah. We define the product of two cosets in this way. But I wouldn't say it is arbitrary! It is A) well-defined and B) gives us a useful theory.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, if you are trying to show this is indeed a ring, there are indirect methods that are far easier.  For example:

Consider the evaluation homomorphism $ev_i:\mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined as follows:

$$f(x) \mapsto f(i)$$

This homomorphism is indeed surjective since, given any $(a + bi) \in \mathbb{C}$, simply take the polynomial $f(x) = a + bx$.  Further, $ker(\phi) = \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$.  Now we apply the isomorphism theorem:

$$\mathbb{R}[x]/ \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{C}$$

So it is certainly a ring, and even a field.

Comment: Yes, but I am searching for the polynomials. I was previously aware of this proof.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.